# Reportlab - Pie chart fill colors

Tags: python, django, graph, reportlab

I am making a simple pie chart in reportlab.  I can not find in the docs how to change each individual pies fill color.

```
pie_chart = Drawing(200, 200)
pc = Pie()
pc.x = 65
pc.y = 15
pc.width = 150
pc.height = 150
pc.data = [65,13,12,9,1]
pc.labels = ['Name','Another','Yet Another','Test','Stack']

pc.slices[1]. // This is where I need the fill color property.

pie_chart.add(pc)
renderPM.drawToFile(pie_chart, '/images/temp/pie_chart.png', 'PNG')
p.drawImage('/images/temp/pie_chart.png', 10, 60, width=150, height=150, mask=None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok there is a couple ways to do this.

The property is .fillColor, but you have to make sure you provide the color to it correctly.  Below are two ways, with CMYK and RGB.

1. Using CMYK
    catColor = PCMYKColor(0,0,0,100)

   pc.slices[0].fillColor = catColor

   [See this snippet](http://www.reportlab.com/snippets/1/)
2. Using RGB Color
    catColor = Color(0.10,0.26,0.46)

   pc.slices[0].fillColor = catColor

   - Obviously you do not need CatColor variable, you can put the lines together.

View more info about colors [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reportlab.com%2Fdocs%2Freportlab-reference.pdf&rct=j&q=reportlab%20documentation&ei=ZXWzTNCVH8LNswaCxdXcDQ&usg=AFQjCNGt9WeP7C0-naiIUZtod3C9W4v9tg&sig2=CJqjCETyjYSfLW8wqPacyA&cad=rja) (reportlab docs, see page 23)

Answer (score 0):

You can use color.HexColor("#f00"). Checkout the following examples`

[Hex color codes](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@s@v@svg2rlg-0.3@svg2rlg.py/190/reportlab.lib.colors.HexColor)